# Set UICollectionViewCell size before content size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with dynamic cell sizing which was working perfectly until I set proportional width constraints on the content inside the cell.

It seems now the `UICollectionViewCell` is sized to the size of the content, whereas actually I want the opposite - the content needs to be sized proportional to the cell size. Guess I'm missing something...

[image][image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = self.collectionView.frame.width
    let height = self.view.frame.height/2.5

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: What layout are you using? Vertical or Horizontal?

Comment: Flow, vertical layout

Comment: Looks like something hugging cell's content. Double check unusable constraints in cell because your sizeForItemAt function looks right.

Comment: What am I looking for specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, fixed by setting estimated size = none in IB

[image]